# c# Data from Access won't show on datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, datagridview

I'm new to C# and I'm struggling to make data from Access to show on datagridview.
So I made a database connection and it works fine. But the button to load data got an error that seems to be saying that there's a problem on the line "connection.Open();"

```
        try
        {

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select Title, Director * from MVDBtable";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


            connection.Close();
        }

        //show error message 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How could you know that the database connection works fine?

Comment: I did the code on the load event for database connection and to show message whether the program successfully or fail to connect to the database. I don't know much about how to check this properly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use correct syntax:

```
string query = "select Title, Director, * from MVDBtable";
```

or, more likely:

```
string query = "select Title, Director from MVDBtable";
```

Comment: Still not working. I was watching some tutorials and realised that they do the insert data function to the database first. Could that be the reason why it doesn't work on my program? Because I haven't done that part yet, just have this code and the database connection code on the load event. I manually put some data directly into MS-Access, it has been a long time since I work on database so maybe that's the mistake I did.

Comment: Can't tell. I don't use the low-level OleDb command stuff. Have a look at _DataTableAdapter_.